# Wrong answer for Project Euler #27

Tags: c++

*Question*
Euler discovered the remarkable quadratic formula:

n² + n + 41

It turns out that the formula will produce 40 primes for the consecutive values n = 0 to 39. However, when n = 40, 402 + 40 + 41 = 40(40 + 1) + 41 is divisible by 41, and certainly when n = 41, 41² + 41 + 41 is clearly divisible by 41.

The incredible formula  n² − 79n + 1601 was discovered, which produces 80 primes for the consecutive values n = 0 to 79. The product of the coefficients, −79 and 1601, is −126479.

Considering quadratics of the form:

n² + an + b, where |a| < 1000 and |b| < 1000

where |n| is the modulus/absolute value of n
e.g. |11| = 11 and |−4| = 4
Find the product of the coefficients, a and b, for the quadratic expression that produces the maximum number of primes for consecutive values of n, starting with n = 0.

---

I tried solving this question using this method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100000000
#define rP(n) (sieve[n>>6]|=(1<<((n>>1)&31)))
#define gP(n) (sieve[n>>6]&(1<<((n>>1)&31)))

int main()
{
    const int S=(int)sqrt((double)MAX);
    unsigned sieve[(MAX>>6)+1]={0};
    int i, j,k,l=0 ;
    vector<long int>prime;
    prime.push_back(2);
    for(i=3;i<=S;i+=2) if(!(gP(i))) {
        k=(i<<1);
        //prime[l++]=i;
        for(j=i*i;j<=MAX;j+=k) rP(j);
    }

    for(i=3;i<=MAX;i+=2)
    { if(!(gP(i))) 
        {prime.push_back(i);
            //cout<<i<<endl;
        }
    }
    int sum1,multi;
    int f,max1=0;
    long int z;
    int a=-999;
    int b=-999;
    bool t;
    for(a;a<=1000;a++)
    {
        for(b;b<=1000;b++)
        {
            sum1=0;
            f=0;
            t=true;
            while(t)
            {
                z=(f*f)+(a*f)+b;
                if(binary_search(prime.begin(),prime.end(),z))
                    sum1++;
                else
                    t=false;

                f++;
            }

            if(sum1>max1)
            {
                max1=sum1;
                multi=a*b;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<multi<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

It was giving me wrong answer, but it gave the right answer hen I declared a,b inside the for loop,i.e.,

```
for(int a=-999;a<=1000;a++)
        {
            for(int b=-999;b<=1000;b++)
            {
                sum1=0;
                f=0;
                t=true;
                while(t)
                {
                    z=(f*f)+(a*f)+b;
                    if(binary_search(prime.begin(),prime.end(),z))
                        sum1++;
                    else
                        t=false;
                    f++;
                }

                if(sum1>max1)
                {
                    max1=sum1;
                    multi=a*b;
                }
            }
        }
```

Please could you explain me the reason for this?

Comment: Rather than using a macro for `rP()` and `gP()`, try using an `inline` function.  The function will have better type efficiency and the `inline` keyword should give the compiler the hint to paste it as inline code.

Answer (score 2):

With the original code:

```
int b=-999;
bool t;
for(a;a<=1000;a++)
{
    for(b;b<=1000;b++)
```

you initialize `b` *once* only. Once the inner loop is done, and the outer restarts, `b` is not re-initialized, and the condition in the loop will be false. That means the inner loop will run only once, no matter how many times you run the outer loop.

With the new code you initialize `b` every time the inner loop starts.

Comment: this actually depends on whether he wanted to initialize them again , but seems this is the case as he got correct answer .